# Getting data from Mysql database with no knowledge of its structure

Tags: java, mysql, database, generics, jdbc

Is there any way in Java how to retrieve data from Mysql database with no knowledge of its structure? Let's say I'm connected to database and I want to get data from a specific table.

I would like to create a list of objects where every object represents one row of the table. Every object has it's private attributes of data type which represents its data type from table.

Comment: Did you try `SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables where table_schema='<your_database_name>';` and then doing `select * from table_name` on each value?

Comment: MySQL has commands like `SHOW TABLE`, and tables storing metadata, and you could code something leveraging that, but you're probably better off letting the database be a database.

Comment: Yes, it's how I get the tables. Now I want to somehow connect SQL data types to Java data types while getting rows from exact table.

Comment: You would need a Map<String, Object> for each row, where the keys are the column names, and the values are the values in these columns. You can't dynamically create a class in Java (well, you can, but you really don't want to go that way). What are you really trying to achieve, at a higher level?

Comment: JB Nizet: Later, I want to map this rows to JSON object so I want to distinguish String type from Number types... I guess I will satisfy with only strings.

Comment: @P.N. it's a Map<String, Object>. Why do you think it would only contain Strings? The strings are the keys. The values are objects, as returned by ResultSet.getObject(). So if you have an int column, it would contain an Integer. To make sothing useful with the JSON, you would need to know its structure, wouldn't you? So, what are you really trying to achieve, at a higher level?